# How can I check if there are changes in my database

Tags: javascript, ajax

What I want is a technique to refresh my div if there are changes in my database. Here is the point,

What i want: How can i condition to know if the first value from my database is lesser than the upcomming value.

In my situation, i put my ajax function to be run every 5secs here is it:

`lastcountQueue` is declared as global in javascript

```
function check_getqueue() {
  $.ajax({
      url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
           lastcountQueue = data[0]['count'];

        }
  });
}
```

Q:where would i put the condition something `if lastcountQueue < data[0]['count];` condition means something if the data is lesser than lastcountQueue it means there was a change in my database portion.

Another Clear Situation for my question:
 I want to make a function like these: the ajax will run every 5 seconds where it query a value to count my no. of queues in database. If my first query is giving me 5 value, and the second is giving me again another 5, then there must be nothing change happens, then if my third value gives me 4, where it is not equal to the last query, then i would do something

Comment: Why don't you put it inside your success function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
function check_getqueue() {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      var tmpCountQ = data[0]['count'];
      if (tmpCountQ < lastcountQueue) {
        // Process the change
      }

      lastcountQueue = tmpCountQ;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: yes sir you got my idea. but how cn i get the lastcountQueue, for example, in my last query i got a return from my DB of 4, then i will store it, and again, if i query in my db again and it returns 3, how can i do it? please help

Comment: @JcJohn Could you please elaborate more, the problem is not very clear

Comment: thats what i want sir, i want to make a function like these: the ajax will run every 5 seconds where it query a value to count my no. of queues in database. If my first query is giving me 5 value, and the second is giving me again another 5, then there must be nothing change happens, then if my third value gives me 4, where it is not equal to the last query, then i would do something

Comment: @JcJohn: Just take my code, or the code from PSo's answer, and fill in the `// Process the change` resp. `//Your logic here` part.

Comment: @ammoQ sir can i ask you again? hmmn. i want to make the lastcountQueue to be an array, something like, i want to create a function to get all the queue_id from my database and store it in javascript array and if there is changes between arrays if the values are not the same i will do something?

Comment: @Jc John: Simple answer: Don't do that. Doing that would mean you have to transfer the whole table every time you poll the server. Better implement a change counter (increases with every change) on the server or use the timestamp of the last update to detect changes; only when there is a change, either get the changes (rather difficult to implement) or the whole table (easier) and process it.

Comment: @ammoQ hello sir can we chat in discussion? i have a question

Comment: @Jc John: Sorry, currently I'm too busy to chat

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated answer:

```js
function check_getqueue() {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl + "sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/" + clinicID + "/" + userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data[0]['count'] != lastcountQueue) {
         //Your logic here
         lastcountQueue = data[0]['count'];
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thats what i want sir, i want to make a function like these: the ajax will run every 5 seconds where it query a value to count my no. of queues in database. If my first query is giving me 5 value, and the second is giving me again another 5, then there must be nothing change happens, then if my third value gives me 4, where it is not equal to the last query, then i would do something

Comment: you just have to check it equal every time, answer updated